# Format Node Stdout Pipe

Tags: node.js, stdout

I've got the following setup to run a number of spawned processes:

`spawn(proc, args, {
   env: process.env,
   cwd: process.env.HOME,
   stdio: [ 'pipe', process.stdout, process.stdout ]
 });`

My curiosity lies in the output streams. I'm curious if there is a way to have the output indented 2 characters? I'd like to have the process' output clearly distinguished.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really asking here.  What overall problem are you actually trying to solve?  The `spawn` API does have any way to automatically modify an output stream if that's what you're asking.  You could of course modify the stream yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to modify the `stdout` so it inserts 2-spaces before each line.

Comment: You could make a transform stream that would add the indent for you.  Many transform examples here: http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html